# select data by date range with year wrapping

Tags: php, mysql

I dont know if this is even possible. I have a MySQL table containing season start and end dates for advertisers. The dates dont change from year to year so they are stored in MM-DD format.

These are normally consective within a year , ie March 1st (03-01) to October 1st. (10-01).

BUT the seasons may wrap around a year end, eg October 1st. (10-01)  to March 1st (03-01) (ie they are closed in the spring & summer)

Now I need to select entries (via PHP) where a date range entered by a user ( say December 1st to December 12th.) falls within advertiser season start/end dates.

Easy enough if the season start/end were mathematically consecutive ( eg 03-01 - 10-01) but how do I do it when they may or may not be consecutive.

Sorry if I havent explained that clearly but my head's about to explode....

Comment: is there any way you can make a small change to the application/table in order to store the year as well ?

Comment: What column types are your season start/end columns?  If they are `DATE` columns, then this problem is trivial to solve, no?  If they are not `DATE` columns, then they should be. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use the proper column type ([DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html)) for this data, and the season wrapping becomes a non-issue.

To get the season(s) that the user-supplied date range applies to:

```
SELECT foo
FROM   seasons_table
WHERE  <user range low> >= season_range_low
AND    <user range high> <= season_range_high
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table
    WHERE CASE 
          WHEN date_start > date_end THEN 
                $date_to_check >= date_start OR  $date_to_check <= date_end 
          ELSE 
                $date_to_check >= date_start AND $date_to_check <= date_end
          END;
```

Comment: +1 That does it nicely, without DATE-ifying.  (Note that no rows will be returned if `$date_to_check IN (date_start, date_end)`, but that's nothing a >= / <= can't fix.)

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to use an AND statement in your SQL to check for the two possibilities:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE
season_start_date <= advertiser_start_date AND
season_end_date >= advertiser_end_date OR
```

No matter what the season end date needs to be a higher value than the ad end date, even if it's in the new year.  So that should work, but I agree with @SoboLAN, it would be much simpler if you just add the year to the date fields.